# How to specify a transformation in GIMP

Tags: gimp, transform, perspective

I have a specific perspective transformation that I want to apply to an image. How can I enter the matrix values manually in GIMP instead of playing around with stretching the image until the numbers come out right (which is virtually impossible)?

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid currently there's no way to specify transformation matrix in Gimp other than writing a plugin/script yourself or using one of the [MathMap](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/schani/mathmap/) operations. MathMap is actually standalone app, but it can be used as a plugin for Gimp.

Comment: MathMap is currently not available on Linux, but you can achieve the same thing in imagemagick using the `-affine -transform` options.

Comment: Oh, but it is available :). The project page misses only “official” binaries, but the source is there. Besides, most distros build their binaries from sources anyway, so…